# ValueError: Transaction gasPrice (0) is too low for the next block, which has a baseFeePerGas of 1

Tags: gas, brownie

I'm working with brownie, and I'm trying to deploy a pretty large smart contract, and I keep running into this:

```
ValueError: Transaction gasPrice (0) is too low for the next block, which has a baseFeePerGas of 1
```

What gives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means 1 of 2 things:

1. You need to set a manual gas price with something like:

```py
some_gas_price = 100000 
contract.deploy({"from": from_account, "gas_price": some_gas_price})
```

or you could use a gas strategy:

```py
from brownie.network.gas.strategies import GasNowStrategy
.
.
.
contract.deploy({"from": from_account,"gas_price": GasNowStrategy("fast")})
```

Or

2. You are trying to deploy a contract that is way too big.

If this is the case, you'll have to reduce the size of your contract.